# Android Studio doesn't show exceptions

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, android-anr-dialog

I have a problem. Android Studio doesn't show exceptions. Instead of this application hangs and `AndroidNotResponding` dialogs appears. But Android Studio `logcat` shows nothing. For example, if I have a `NullPointerException` in my program, it will not be shown but ANR dialog will appear.  How can I repair this and catch my exceptions.

Comment: Please clear all temp file and close every things and restart and run again

Comment: make sure there is nothing in your filter search box.

Comment: What kind of code causes this problem? Are you sure that your app. doesn't actually freeze? If it freezes, then fix that problem first and see if Android Studio then works as you would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I've found solution. It was because of GoogleAnalitycs. No exception was shown because of this line

```
mTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
```

If you have the same problem just comment this line and everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have Android Monitor set properly in Android Studio. In the top-left corner, select the correct device. Then select the proper log level, preferably *Error* in this case. And the on the far-right select *No Filters*.

Comment: no, it's not this case. Other things appear in logcat, such as my log for debugging or other info, but exception are not shown

Answer (score 0):

disconnect phone and reconnect usually help me: log reappears in logcat
also check no filter is applied.
also changing filter helped me in past.

other solutions is debug. check where it crash and wrap with try/catch and inspect Exception.

other solution is use Fabric.io (https://fabric.io/) : maybe is overkilling but found it very useful